# link outside of updatepanel vanishes after partial postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got a simple href link **outside** of an updatepanel that vanishes after a partial postback.  I can understand if it was within an updatepanel that it would vanish but this is outside of an update panel.

Simple markup

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updData" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
               <ContentTemplate>
                <!--SOme asp.net grid view control -->
               </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
<a href="#" class="scrollup" title="back to top">Scroll</a>  <!-- Heres the vanishing link -->
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a> <!-- Added this for a test -->
</asp:Content>
```

The href that has class scrollup disappears, and for a test I added a link to yahoo and even that disappears after a partial postback.  I cannot understand why they disappear since they are outside of the update panel.

The class `scrollup` is simply there for jquery purposes to reference this link:

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        marginTop = ($(document).scrollTop() - scroll) + marginTop;
        scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            cc.addClass("f-nav");
            cc.addClass("addShadow");
            cc.addClass("addShadow");
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            cc.removeClass("f-nav");
            cc.removeClass("addShadow");
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });

 $('.scrollup').click(function () {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: You mean <a href="#" class="scrollup" title="back to top">Scroll</a> is no more in the renderized dom?

Comment: Both the links the test to yahoo and the one with class scroll up have vanished from the page. If I view source on the page I still see the actual hyperlinks in the rendered html, they just dont appear on the page.

Comment: I would say you hit ever fade-out statement

Comment: The meaning of that is ?

Comment: sorry for mispelling, seems your code fall always in the else branch

Comment: @Infer-On that is not the case because the sample test link for yahoo does not display as well, and that does not have a class associated with it.

Comment: sorry, I don't want pollute your question with my comments, but, or other script hit your hyperlinks, otherwise its black magic :(

Comment: @Infer-On I moved it to the site master page and all is well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after looking through this, I found that if I place within the site.master page the hyperlink this ends up working.  So it appears to be a strange issue but I was able to take it out of the .aspx page and simply add to the site master page.